# Python requests - can't login to a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

My question is simple.
I'm trying to login to the site `opensubtitles.org`,

with the username `oshribsintec`

and the password `1q2w3e!Q@W#E`.

When I login from the browser my login is successful.

However when I use Python `requests` - for some reason I get blocked.

This is my code to log in:

```
payload = {
    'user': 'oshribsintec',
    'inUserPass': '1q2w3e!Q@W#E'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    p=s.post('https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/login/', data=payload)
```

And when I'm copying `p.text` to text file, and name it `something.html` and open the result in browser - I see the message `"You are not logged in!"`.

Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: IDK, it didn't seem like it was deleted when I asked you to add more details there. Anyway, moot point now. I've removed my -1. You should have updated your old question with more details, because it's essentially the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example to log-in to `opensubtitles.org`:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {
    'a': "login",
    'redirect': "/en/search/subs",
    'user': "oshribsintec",
    'password': "1q2w3e!Q@W#E",
    'remember': "on"
}

login_url = 'https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/login/redirect-|en|search|subs'

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.post(login_url, data=data).content, 'html.parser')

    # for verification, print who's logged in:
    print(soup.select_one('#logindetail').get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
```

Prints:

```
Logged-in as: oshribsintec | Log-out
```

Comment: BTW Andrej, Can you please tell me how did you know to call `'https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/login/redirect-|en|search|subs'` URL? The login window appears as a popup, how did you find the correct URL? Thanks.

Comment: @BinyaminEven I opened Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab (Chrome has something similar) and upon login, the page made request to this URL (with correct parameters).

Comment: Thank you! and how did you translate it to python?

Comment: @BinyaminEven The parameters are in `data=` parameter, URL I saw in the Developer tools and the rest is easy -> just do `.post(...)` request.